# How does the Android emulator emulate the RAM?

Tags: android-emulator, ram

How does the Google Android emulator emulate the RAM?

Does it use the physical RAM of the host or use secondary memory like the hard disk?

Comment: The properties of RAM are so unique (speed, latency, ..) that you can only emulator RAM with real physical RAM. Even a very fast SSD is about 1.000-100.000 times slower regarding the access latency.

Comment: @Robert I know that but I want to make sure. if there is a documentation/reference, it will be great.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Android Virtual Devices are emulated using [QEMU](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline) hypervisor which use physical memory. As any process, the allocated memory pages can be unmapped and swapped to disk or other storage by the host system.

For more information: [An overview of memory management in QEMU for Android.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/android/platform_external_qemu/master/docs/QEMU-MEMORY-MANAGEMENT.TXT)